# gdb: how to set a breakpoint in a file with spaces

Tags: gdb

How does one set a breakpoint in a file that has a space in its filename or path?

It seems like this is not possible with GDB or am I missing something?

```
/tmp$ g++ -g debugee\ space.cpp 
/tmp$ gdb ./a.out 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
...
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
(gdb) break "/tmp/debugee space.cpp:4"
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4007e3: file debugee space.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) break "/tmp/debugee space.cpp":4
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x4007e3.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4007e3: file debugee space.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: Function "/tmp/debugee space.cpp:4" not defined.
Error in re-setting breakpoint 2: Function "/tmp/debugee space.cpp:4" not defined.
Hello, world!
[Inferior 1 (process 14188) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this looks like a regression in gdb 7.4. I reported the bug: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13798

Answer (score 0):

works for me (tm), didn't try with c++ though...

```
cat space\ spaces.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int tmp(void) {
    int a = 42;
    printf("%d", a);
}

int main(void) {
    tmp();

    return 0;
}

$ gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from /home/user/slask/gdb/a.out...done.
(gdb) b "space spaces.c":5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004f3: file space spaces.c, line 5.
(gdb) i b
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x00000000004004f3 in tmp at space spaces.c:5
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/slask/gdb/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, tmp () at space spaces.c:5
5       printf("%d", a);
(gdb)
```

Comment: what version of gdb are you using? I get the same error with your app and when compiling with gcc. I have gdb 7.4

Comment: Same issue for me: Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: Function "/tmp/space test.c:5" not defined. (gdb 7.4)